# If $\|\langle x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_n\rangle\|\le \delta$, can I say that $x_i \le \delta$ for each $i$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

If I have a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that is in a neighborhood of $0$ that is large $\delta$, i.e. $\left \| x \right \| \le \delta$ can I say that all of its components must be $x_i \le \delta$ for each $i =1,\dots,n$?

Answer (score 3):

Not for an arbitrary norm on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Consider the norm $\|(x,y)\| =\frac12|x| + \frac12|y|$. Then $\|(1,0)\|=\frac12$ but the first coordinate is not $\le \frac12$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Suppose not. Then you would have $\|x\| > \delta$. Just write it as $\|x\| = (x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2)^{1/2}$ and you will see it. I am assuming, of course, that you are using the canonical norm in $\Bbb{R}^N$. Otherwise, the fact my not be true.

Answer (score 2):

In general for any orthogonal projection $P$ then we that $\|Px\| \leq \|x\|$. This includes the projection onto each component of the vector in some basis.